# Can I flip any hanging beams flat on their side?

Tags: framing, attic, joists, beam

The framing in my attic is annoying because it's very difficult
work near the roof edge, due to the presence
of what I think are called [hanging beams](https://findanyanswer.com/goto/115633) -- large timbers
on edge attached to the tops of the ceiling joists.

[image]

At first the beams made no sense to me because I assumed their
job was to address side-to-side motion/forces in the joists -- and if so,
couldn't I just flip them onto their sides (flat) to get the same structural
benefit without eating up so much of the vertical space where I need to work?

After more research, I now wonder whether I misunderstood their purpose.
I assume most of the answers to my question will be disappointing and that
I'll have to work around them, but I'll ask anyway:

Are these hanging beams needed at all or were they just artifacts on the
initial framing process?

Can I flip them so they are flat rather than on edge?

Finally, the hanging beams run the full length on the house (one full run
on each side of the house). However, there is one section where that
pattern is broken and the beam simply ends -- in a way such that it is not
actually resting on a load bearing wall at the end (left side of the photo). Which makes me think
the beam is no longer able to serve whatever its initial purpose was.
This exception to the rule occurs over the kitchen where a big remodel was done
by a prior owner and where I can see that the original 2x6 joists (found in most of the house)
were replaced with beefier 2x8 joints. Perhaps that remodel made the hanging
beam over the kitchen irrelevant and it no longer had to extend all the way
to a load bearing wall? And if so, could I at least remove or flip that hanging beam?

Can anyone shed more definitive light on these questions?

Comment: If you try that your ceiling may at minimum have cracks all over at worst collapse.

Comment: Those don't look like hanging beams.  IIUC, the hanging beam should connect the rafter to the ceiling joist.  I don't see yours connected to the rafter.  https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-uses-of-a-hanging-beam

Comment: I still wouldn't change any structural component of my house, even if someone on the internet said it was OK.

Comment: Upset beam is another term for this. It would be highly unusual to have such a significant chunk of lumber there without it serving a structural purpose, and flipping it sideways will take its load capacity / stiffness down by a factor of at least 16 if not more. Wow. No insulation at all in this attic...

Comment: What do you need to work on down there that warrants changing your framing?

Comment: Isn’t that called a strongback?

Comment: it's not supporting the joists shown in the photo maybe there a clue as to its purpose further along.  there's a slim possibility that thart it was left over when the design was changed usiring construction.

Comment: @SteveSether It's possible I have incorrect terminology – figuring out the correct name is part of my question, I suppose. The beam is **not** connected to the rafters. Rather it is nailed to every ceiling joint. The photo shows only the unusual beam (the one that fails to extend all the way to a load bearing wall). The other similar beams run the full length of the house, all the way to load bearing walls.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, I was thinking the same; that's why I'm asking around. The beam is really making it difficult to get access to the electrical and air sealing locations I need to address before adding new insulation to the entire attic. And because it's attached so oddly (no load bearing support on one side, and merely toenailed to ceiling joists, nothing else) makes me wonder about its current structural purpose, if any.

Comment: @LeeSam Perhaps so. It's toenailed to the tops of the ceiling joists. Has no contact with the roof rafters.

Comment: If they cross walls, even if the (cut in remodelling?) end is not at a wall, they still carry loads to the walls they cross. The "cut not at a wall" cantilevers back to the nearest wall.